# Difference between 2 renders

Tags: rendering, animation

I have render the image with CPU.

[image]

And [animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcFjP.jpg) done with GPU

Why there is difference between 2 light. Same mesh. Same lights. Nothing added or change. So why there is much difference in lights. Any suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Can you share a file or usefull part from it?

Comment: In what format have you saved the animation?

Comment: I agree with @atek. When I tested rendering with the two devices (GPU and CPU), I got some wildly different lighting results.

Comment: @RobinBetts MP4

Comment: Would a good first step be to compare like with like, in a non-lossy format? i.e CPU rendered PNG vs, GPU rendered PNG?